# Combining two tables result into JSON - SQL server

Tags: sql, sql-server

I am having two tables **STUDENT** and **MASTER** as follows

`CREATE TABLE student(sid int,sname varchar(10),saddress varchar(30))`

`CREATE TABLE master(mid int,mname varchar(10),maddress varchar(30))`

**Now I want the JSON Structure as**

```
{
    "student": [
        {
            "sid": "value",
            "sname": "value",
            "saddress": "value"
        }
    ],
    "master": [
        {
            "mid": "value",
            "mname": "value",
            "maddress": "value"
        }
    ]
}
```

In short I can say:

```
{
"table1":[],
"table2":[]
}
```

I have tried this but result is not as expected

```
    SELECT * FROM student,master FOR JSON AUTO
```

**Can any one help me to form the required JSON Structure from the query ??**

Comment: While asking a question, you need to provide a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example):
(1) DDL and sample data population, i.e. CREATE table(s) plus INSERT T-SQL statements. 
(2) What you need to do, i.e. logic and your code attempt implementation of it in T-SQL. 
(3) Desired output, based on the sample data in #1 above.
(4) Your SQL Server version (SELECT @@version;).

Answer (score 4):

Couple ideas:

```sql
SELECT student,
       [master] --This is a poor choice for an object, as master is the name of a system database
FROM (VALUES((SELECT * FROM dbo.student FOR JSON AUTO),
             (SELECT * FROM dbo.[master] FOR JSON AUTO)))V(student,[master])
FOR JSON AUTO;

SELECT (SELECT *
        FROM dbo.student
        FOR JSON AUTO) AS student,
       (SELECT *
        FROM dbo.[master] --This is a poor choice for an object, as master is the name of a system database
        FOR JSON AUTO) AS [master]
FOR JSON PATH;
```